# Eclipseでapplication.propertiesの値を取得すると文字化けする

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseでapplication.propertiesのファイルをUTF-8に変えたところ、
下記で取得すると文字化けしてしまいます。
文字化けせずに取得する方法はありますでしょうか。

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
String test = bundle.getString("test");
```

★application.propertiesは下記のとおり

```
test=テストです。
```

こちらをためしてみたものの、うまくいかず…

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
String test = null;
test = bundle.getString("test");
test = new String( test.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ) , "JISAutoDetect" );
```

またEclipseの設定は
ウインドウ->一般->コンテンツタイプで
javaプロパティファイルのデフォルトエンコードをUTF-8にしています。

Answer (score 1):

- [blog.k11i.biz: Java のプロパティファイルは UTF-8 エンコーディングで記述したい](http://blog.k11i.biz/2014/09/java-utf-8.html)

上記サイトで説明されている通りで実現可能かと思います。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ResourceBundleUtf8Control extends ResourceBundle.Control {

    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle(final String baseName, final Locale locale, final String format,
        final ClassLoader loader, final boolean reload)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException {
        final String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
        final String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, "properties");

        try (InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            return new PropertyResourceBundle(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

上のようなクラスを定義し、使用箇所では次のように記述します。

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application", new ResourceBundleUtf8Control());
```

なお、  [Java9からはResourceBundleのデフォルトエンコーディングがUTF-8になった](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-new-features-3745613.html#JDK-8027607) ので上記のような手法は不要です。質問文に記載されたコードそのままで想定どおり取得できるようになっています。

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
System.out.println(bundle.getString("test"));
```

---

ただ、ファイル名を `application.properties` としているのが気にかかりました。それは本当にリソースバンドルでしょうか。

例えばそれが[Spring Bootの設定ファイル](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)なのであれば、リソースバンドルでなく単なるプロパティファイルなので、 **Java9以降であっても UTF-8 に変換するのでなく ISO 8859-1 で扱うべきです。**

[Properties#load(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)):

> 入力ストリームはload(Reader)で規定される単純行指向フォーマットで、ISO 8859-1文字エンコーディングを使用することが前提されます。つまり、各バイトは1つのLatin1文字です。 Latin1にない文字、および一部の特殊文字は、キーや要素内で『Java™言語仕様』のセクション3.3で定義されているUnicodeエスケープを使用して表現されます。

事実、Spring Bootでは `application.properties` をそのように扱います:

- [Read application.properties using ISO 8859-1 #10565](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/10565)

---

ISO 8859-1エンコーディングされたプロパティファイルを Eclipse 上で想定通り(日本語も読めるように)表示させたい場合、次のようなプラグインが使えるかと思います:

- [Properties Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/properties-editor)

Comment: プロパティファイルについての詳細は質問から逸れるので別にまとめました: https://qiita.com/yukihane/items/eae583604381a60a91bd